# xubuntu power pc low requirements iso mirror

Tags: upgrade, xubuntu, powerpc

I am trying to restore an old iMac G3 with Xubuntu and I succeeded in installing 6.04 but I could not find a download for 14.04 PPC that supported installation below 194mb of RAM. I do not wish to spend any money on upgrading the RAM. I am simply curious if you could link me a disk image or show me how to directly upgrade Xubuntu 6.04 to 14.04.

Comment: Also you can't upgrade from 6.04 to 14.04, you need to go via the official LTS releases.

Answer (score 2):

Just recently put Lubuntu 12.04 on my old imac g3 500.  It was a bit tricky, but here's what happened with me.  Had to start with 12.04 for ppc.  No GUI when I was done, only a command line.  It asked me if I wanted to upgrade to 14.04.1 and since I really hadn't gotten what I wanted, I went ahead with it.  Loaded up nicely and now have a good GUI.  Some minor graphics issues, but very workable.  I did it with 256 MB RAM.  Have since upgraded to 1GB, which was a pretty minor cost and it runs way faster.

Comment: I am still working on this imac and I dod the same thing with ubuntu 12.04 but when I upgraded it there was still no GUI

Answer (score 0):

This won't be a supported action.  While a minimal installation disc would typically be used to build up something anew while working with that memory constraint, [the last one released that supports 32-bit PowerPC architecture was for 12.04](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD#A32-bit_PowerPC.2A.2A).  While a [mini.iso image for 14.04 does exist](http://ports.ubuntu.com/dists/trusty/main/installer-powerpc/current/images/powerpc/netboot/mini.iso) it isn't even referenced in the documentation.

As noted on Xubuntu's [system requirements page](http://xubuntu.org/getxubuntu/requirements/):

> *To install or try Xubuntu within the Desktop/Live DVD, you need 256 MB of memory, if you are using the Minimal CD, which uses the non-graphical Debian Installer and downloads packages as you install, you need 128 MB of memory.*
>
> *Once installed, you should have at least 512 MB of memory.*

You can attempted the installation but your results may not necessarily be satisfactory in terms of performance.  Using the minimal installation disc you can choose what mix of packages you wish to install in case you do not wish to fully install all that Xubuntu ships.  There is currently no testing done at all on PowerPC architecture for Xubuntu-related packages.